# Auto-complete a switch-case in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am a student learning Game design as well as Programming in C# and have been using Visual Studio for a while. I recently switched back to Visual Studio Code for a recent project and i have been annoyed by a a certain lacking auto complete feature.

Using Visual Studio Code, how does one auto complete a switch case in the same way like Visual Studio does?

I have searched the Extension Market in Visual Studio Code and i have  found no single extension that achieves this. I have also searched (although not in depth) Microsoft's documentation about Visual Studio Code for this feature yet nothing has come up in my findings about this.

If there is not any official method, is there at least any way possible to achieve a similar effect?